# Multi threading and C# exception. File is being used by another process

Tags: c#, multithreading, file, locking

I am writing an application in which an other Window form application will write into the file and then my file will read the file and perform some task which will take some time around 2 hr. So I want to implement threading so that whenever file length becomes greater than zero,My application should start a thread and then main thread should  start looking for file size and if again in some time  length of file become greater than zero then Main thread should a separate thread for that.All there should stop once the task is completed by them.

Kindly suggest How I can achieve this and also have a look on my code as below:

Code for Window form application:

```
const string inputfile=@"C:\Users\abc\Documents\input.txt";
        try {
                using (FileStream fs = File.Open(inputfile, FileMode.Open))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fs))
                    {
                        writer.Write(textBox1.Text);
                        button1.Enabled = false;
                        writer.Close();
                        fs.Close();
                    }

                }

            }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("File is locked by some process try again");
            Thread.Sleep(10*1000);
            Application.Exit();
        }
```

My application code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        while(true)
        {
            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(inputfile);
                if(fi.Length>0)
                {
                    Thread th1=new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadingTest.runCommand));
                    th1.Start();
                    if(Variable.stop)
                    th1.Abort();

                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("File.Empty");
                    Thread.Sleep(30 * 1000);
                }
        }
```

When I run my application I get an exception "C# exception. File is being used by another process" Kindly suggest some useful points about my approach.

Comment: You can use another file to sync.  For ex, create a file "My update is finished", when it is created other process can try to read the original file. After then, it can remove the sync file to signal other process.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than doing this in a loop, you could use FileSystemWatcher to monitor that file by subscribing to the onChanged event. You can find some documentation and samples here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx

The file may still be locked by the other process, so try opening it until it becomes unlocked :

```
while(true)
{
     try {
            /* open and process file */
            break;
     }
     catch(Exception e)
     {
            /* file unavailable */
     }

     Thread.Sleep(100); // Wait for the file to be available
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't want to use `Thread.Abort()`. Second, if you can modify the file-creating application, make it signal you that the file is ready (through creating another file as marker or releasing a named mutex or by remoting or wcf...). Or let the app create a new file (with a unique name) each time.

If such a modification is not possible, you have to use the file lock as synchronization mechanism. That means just try to open it repeatedly and hope you don't miss the time before  the file-creating app takes the lock again.